# Will this code return UIView as its return type

Tags: objective-c

I have read this in a code
the code is as follows

```
- (UIView *)headerView
{

// your code for the function

}
```

in this code the what is the return type of the function?
is it UIView...?

Comment: Yes of course if is a `UIView` or child of `UIView`. Because it is clearly stated. The return type in Objective-C is declared in `()` before the method name. So `-(void)` is an instance method without a return, `-(UIView *)` return a pointer to a `UIView`.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but you might want to read a tutorial. This is _really_ basic stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will return the *UIView*

For Example:

write in any class in your `viewDidAppear` method

```
UIView *view = [self returnView];
```

and the `returnView` function is:

```
-(UIView *) returnView{
// your function code 
// for now you may test it as
return self.view;
}
```